# Windows 10 laptab leave music on during sleep

Tags: windows-10, tablet

So I have a fully featured windows 10 laptop to tablet convertible. I use it mostly as a tablet so I was looking for  a way to get it working like most tablets do , so like if you press the power button the screen blacks out and any music running remains playing in the background. Right now pressing the start button makes it go into sleep which makes it play no music.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you would like to make the screen turn off (instead of windows default "sleep") on power button press action. To do so, go to

**Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options**

click on **"Edit Plan Settings"** next to your currently selected plan

next click on **"Change advanced power settings"**

A new window should pop up - find the **"Power buttons and lid"** position and click it. Next reveal **"Power button"** list and change both positions from "sleep" to "Turn off display". Accept by clicking **"OK"**

@Edit - a screenshot of what it looks like on my Win 10 laptop
[image: a screenshot of what it looks like on my Win 10 laptop]

Comment: I don't seem to have the turn off display option. Only Sleep, Hibernate, Do nothing, shutdown.

Comment: Have you clicked the "Change settings that are currently unavailable" text above the shown box?

Comment: @NotoriousJ I think clicking  "Change settings that are currently unavailable" as ~jatuttle0 suggested should solve your problem. If not you could consider using third-party utility such as http://www.thewindowsclub.com/screenoff-turn-off-windows-laptop-screen (note: I didn't try the software before)

Comment: @Greg I just tried that didn't work. Is that 3rd party app the only option left?

Comment: @NotoriousJ Hmm, you always turn off and turn on display via your custom created shortcut (fired via your custom defined shortcut) - just as in this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-a-shortcut-or-hotkey-to-turn-off-the-monitor/

If the "Change settings that are currently unavailable" didn't work I am afraid I don't know any other way to achieve this only by using windows settings dialogs.

Comment: @Greg the shortcut seems to be an amazing idea.